# как в $_SERVER передать get запрос

Tags: javascript, php, mvc, url, route

имею самописный роут 
у меня есть параметр get который работает в index 
то есть index/?page=1
как мне прировнять get параметр в условии?
что-бы тип такого
`/?page=  === $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`
а цыфра была бы динамической

```
 $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    // основной путь
    define('URL_ROUTE', '/index.php');


    if(URL_ROUTE .
        '/' == $url)
    {
        Controller::index();
    }
```

потому что за каждым разом прописывать

```
    elseif (URL_ROUTE .
        '/?page=1' == $url)
    {
        Controller::index();
    }
    elseif (URL_ROUTE .
        '/?page=2' == $url)
    {
        Controller::index();
    }
    elseif (URL_ROUTE .
        '?page=3' == $url)
    {
        Controller::index();
    }
```

это не выход

Comment: Вам помогут регулярные выражения https://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/regulyarnye-vyrazheniya-php.html
Ещё можно разбивать url на части и сравнивать без `?page=...`
А ещё лучше воспользоваться готовым роутом, коих великое множество.

Comment: я решил так, создал переменную которая отслеживает get запрос, elseif(URL_ROUTE .
    '/?page='.$get === $url)
{
    Controller::index();
}